# Blurry Terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Why is the text in terminal blurry?]

I have been using *Visual Studio Code* for a few months, but for some reason, it just became blurry. The only thing I really changed was the theme. I set it to default but it is still blurry. Why is this occurring?

Comment: try changing font size

Answer (score 6):

I had to set Gpu Acceleration for the integrated terminal from default `auto` to either `off` or `canvas`.

In the settings.json that is achieved with:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "canvas",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing editor font size and window zoom level:

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
}
```